# Handling multiple fields with BuildRowsetFromString

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have multiple fields that have multiple values per email address. I have a policy number field and that can have multiple policy numbers and then I have a price field that holds the price for each of those policy numbers. The prices and policies are delimited by the pipe.

[Policy_Number] value is 340575181|340575182
[Policy_Price] value is 0.00|0

My current code

```
%%[

Set @Policy_Number_Values = BuildRowsetFromString([Policy_Number],'|')

for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@Policy_Number_Values) do

    Set @row = Row(@Policy_Number_Values, @i)
    Set @policy = Field(@row,1)

    Set @Policy_Price_Values = BuildRowsetFromString([Policy_Price],"|")
    Set @Policy_Name_SKU = BuildRowsetFromString([Policy_Name_SKU],"|")
    Set @Coverage_End_Date = BuildRowsetFromString([Coverage_End_Date],"|")

    for @j = 1 to Rowcount(@Policy_Price_Values) do

        Set @rowj = Row(@Policy_Price_Values, @j)
        Set @price = Field(@rowj,1)

    ]%%   

        Your contract number: %%Policy_Number%% or Policy: %%=v(@policy)=%%
        Your purchase: %%=v(@Policy_Name_SKU)=%%
        Total price of plan: $%%Policy_Price%% or Price: $%%=v(@Price)=%% 
        Deductible amount: $0.00 
        Coverage start date*: %%Coverage_Start_Date%% 
        Coverage end date: %%=v(@Coverage_End_Date)=%% 

    %%[ next @j ]%%

%%[ next @i ]%%
```

However it outputs 4 instances (two for `next @j` and two for `next @i`) and I only want to display 2.

My current output is:

```
Your contract number: 340575181
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0.00
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:

Your contract number: 340575181
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:

Your contract number: 340575182
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0.00
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:

Your contract number: 340575182
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
Your contract number: 340575181
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0.00
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:

Your contract number: 340575182
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0.00
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you update your question with 1) a sample of the values in `[Policy_Number]` and `[Policy_Price]` and 2) an example of the desired output?

Comment: Hi @Adam Springs,  The value for [Policy_Number] is 340575181|340575182 and for [Policy_Price] is 0.00|0   

I would like it to return something like this:   

`Your contract number: 340575181|340575182 or Policy: 340575181  
Your purchase:    
Total price of plan: $0.00|0 or Price: $0.00   
Deductible amount: $0.00   
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015   
Coverage end date:   

Your contract number: 340575181|340575182 or Policy: 340575181   
Your purchase:   
Total price of plan: $0.00|0 or Price: $0   
Deductible amount: $0.00   
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015   
Coverage end date: `

Comment: You want to output the `|` characters?

Comment: @Adam Springs: Something like this come out:  
`Your contract number: 340575181
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0.00
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:

Your contract number: 340575182
Your purchase:
Total price of plan: $0.00
Deductible amount: $0.00
Coverage start date*: 8/13/2015
Coverage end date:`

I update the main post to show my current out. If you notice I get 4 instances/blocks of content of Contract Number and purchase price. I just want two. One for Policy # 340575181 and another for 340575182.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not extracting the data from your rowsets in your inner loop.  You'll need to do use the `field()` and `row()` functions on the `SKUs` and `EndDates`.

I also pulled the policy number out of the inner loop and added the output to the outer loop:

```
%%[

Set @Policy_Number_Values = BuildRowsetFromString([Policy_Number],'|')

for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@Policy_Number_Values) do

    Set @row = Row(@Policy_Number_Values, @i)
    Set @policy = Field(@row,1)

    ]%%
        <br><br>Your contract number: %%Policy_Number%% or Policy: %%=v(@policy)=%%
    %%[

    Set @Policy_Price_Values = BuildRowsetFromString([Policy_Price],"|")
    Set @Policy_Name_SKU = BuildRowsetFromString([Policy_Name_SKU],"|")
    Set @Coverage_End_Date = BuildRowsetFromString([Coverage_End_Date],"|")

    for @j = 1 to Rowcount(@Policy_Price_Values) do

        Set @prices = Row(@Policy_Price_Values, @j)
        Set @price = Field(@prices,1)

        set @skus =  Row(@Policy_Name_SKU, @j)
        set @sku =  Field(@skus,1)

        set @endDates = Row(@Coverage_End_Date, @j)
        set @endDate = Field(@endDates,1)

    ]%%   
        <br>Your purchase: %%=v(@sku)=%% 
        <br>Total price of plan: $%%Policy_Price%% or Price: $%%=v(@price)=%% 
        <br>Deductible amount: $0.00 
        <br>Coverage start date*: %%Coverage_Start_Date%% 
        <br>Coverage end date: %%=v(@endDate)=%%

    %%[ next @j ]%%

%%[ next @i ]%%
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This did what I needed.